# Added text-overflow: ellipsis to span with html elements

Tags: html, css

I have a span element with some text in it that I need to add the text-overflow: ellipsis class to.   The issue I am having is the text may contain some html elements inside it.. for example

```
<button width="75px">
    <span width="25px"> something </span>
    <span>"text string 1" <sup>asdf</sup> "text string 2"</span>
</button>
```

Here is the css that I have around this span:

```
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
```

If the span ends comes before the `<sup>` tag it will show as "text stri..." as expected.  my issue is if the end comes after the `</sup>` tag it will not add the ellipsis and show as "text string 1<sup>asdf</sup> text str" (cutting off the string with no ellipses)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which elements do you have the `text-overflow` declared to? The `span` as well as the `sup`?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I have it applied to the span itself.   I tried with adding the class to all children of the span and same behaviour

Comment: Try declaring those overflow styles to a containing element of the `span`, rather than the `span` itself.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I tried that, same behaviour

Comment: Have you tried rebooting, or a human sacrifice? Joking. I think you'll need to share your markup for the best response and feedback, it'll be far more easier for anyone to troubleshoot as well.

Comment: Seems to work as expected in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/u714sahy/ The ellipsis displays regardless of how wide or narrow I make the span. Edit: tested in FF, SF, IE, Edge too. Can you made a fiddle or pen that that reproduces the bug?